# I keep getting an error when I try to knitr

Tags: html, r, r-markdown

I clicked on New file then selected R markdown. When I click knit it doesn't work.
I have uninstalled and installed R Studio twice and still nothing. Below is the error I keep getting.

```
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  namespace 'htmltools' 0.5.5 is already loaded, but >= 0.5.7 is required
Calls: <Anonymous> ... is_bs_theme -> loadNamespace -> namespaceImport -> loadNamespace
Execution halted
```

Comment: The error message indicates that you need to update the htmltools package.